# RSpec - How to properly use doubles and stub methods on helper objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, double, stub, rspec-mocks

An action of a Rails controller makes an instance of a helper class (say `SomeService`), which performs some work and returns a results, something along the lines of:

```
def create
  ...
  result = SomeService.new.process
  ...
end
```

I want to stub what `SomeService#process` returns.

My question is - how do I do this?

The following works:

```
allow_any_instance_of(SomeService).to receive(:process).and_return('what I want')
```

However, the `rspec-mock` documentation discourages the use of `allow_any_instance_of` for the [reasons states here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#settings-mocks-or-stubs-on-any-instance-of-a-class):

> The rspec-mocks API is designed for individual object instances, but this feature operates on entire classes of objects. As a result there are some semantically confusing edge cases. For example in expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).twice it isn't clear whether each specific instance is expected to receive name twice, or if two receives total are expected. (It's the former.)
>
> Using this feature is often a design smell. It may be that your test is trying to do too much or that the object under test is too complex.
>
> It is the most complicated feature of rspec-mocks, and has historically received the most bug reports. (None of the core team actively use it, which doesn't help.)

I think the idea is to do something like this:

```
some_service = instance_double('SomeService')
allow(some_service).to receive(:process).and_return('what I want')
```

However, how do I make the controller use the double and not make a new instance
of `SomeService`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do something like this.

```
let(:fake_service) { your double here or whatever }

before do
  allow(SomeService).to receive(:new).and_return(fake_service)
  # this might not be needed, depending on how you defined your `fake_service`
  allow(fake_service).to receive(:process).and_return(fake_results)
end
```

Comment: What about if the `SomeService`  class only call a class method. Something like `SomeService.some_class_method`, and we need to test that `some_class_method` was executed?

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano: yes, what about it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev For example, how can I test that the `new` method was called on `SomeService`?
The only way that I could achive that is creating a method `some_service_class` in the controller class that returned `SomeService` and then stubbing that method to return the spy `allow_any_instance_of(SomeController).to(receive(:some_service_class).and_return(service_class_spy))`, and then in the test `expect(service_class_spy).to have_received(:new)`.
I don't like this way, I think that is unclean. Is there a better way?
PS: Ask me anything, may be I was not clear.

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano just `expect(SomeService).to receive(:some_class_method)`? No need for spies or anything

Comment: @SergioTulentsev for some reason that does not work for me. To add more information, the SomeService class is a worker from [Shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to remodel the way you interface with your Service Object:

```
class SomeService
  def self.call(*args)
    new(*args).tap(&:process)
  end

  def initialize(*args)
    # do stuff here
  end

  def process
    # do stuff here
  end

  def success?
    # optional method, might make sense according to your use case
  end
end
```

Since this is a project-wide convention, we know every `.call` returns the service object instance, which we query for things such as `#success?`, `#error_messages`, etcettera (largely dependent on your use cases).

When testing clients of this class, we should only verify they call the class method `.call` with the correct params, which is as straightforward as mocking the returned value.

The unit tests for this class method should attest it:
- calls `.new` with the proper params;
- calls `#process` on the created instance;
- returns the created instance (not the result of process).

Having a class method as main point of entry of your service object interface favors flexibility. Both `#initialize` and `#process` could be made private, but I prefer not to for testing purposes.